# Tool to identify Internet Explorer rendering differences with css

Tags: web-development, css, internet-explorer, compatibility

I develop website using chrome and mac os as development environment.

Since my audience is pretty specific I don't feel the necessity for too much backward compatibility with IE8 and less.

However to my great dismay, even IE9 looks totally broken...

I would like to know if there's on the web a tool that could tell me what probably went wrong with IE, that is a webapp that parse the rendered css and check which rules are probably totally broken in IE9.

Answer (score 2):

There are no tools for this (making sure your HTML and CSS validates are the best you can do). To effectively troubleshoot this you need to know the limitations, bugs, and quirks of each version of IE. [Caniuse.com](http://www.caniuse.com) will tell you what version of IE supports which browser technology. Reading [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com) and Googling "IE bugs" will be *very* enlightening.

(I find that if your code is clean, validates, and renders properly in Firefox and Chrome that your IE issues should be minimal. If that's not the case the odds are you probably can improve your existing code before revisiting IE layout issues.)

Comment: They suggested me that the meta <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" /> could be the guilty. Now i have to find a way to change it to <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"> (as suggested here: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/design/snippets-html5-boilerplate/) in a non destructive way on wordpress